# Why is Scala's tail recursion slower than that of Java?

Tags: java, scala, jvm, tail-recursion

Scala code for simple addition using tail recursion

```
def add(list : List[Int],sum:Int):Int = {
    //Thread.dumpStack()
    if (list.isEmpty) {
        sum
    } else {
        val headVal  = list.head
        add(list.tail, sum + headVal)
    }
}
```

Below is the java code for addition in recursive mode.

```
public static int add(List<Integer> list, Integer sum) {
    // Thread.dumpStack();
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        return sum;
    } else {
        int headVal = list.remove(0);
        return add(list, sum + headVal);
    }
}
```

The Java version runs at least 10 times faster. Ran this for 1000 entries. Measured time by using `System.nanoTime()` API before and after.

Scala version 2.10, java version Java 7. Same JVM properties for both run.

Comment: I have learned that performance measurement is a bit tricky and full of pitfalls even for somewhat experienced programmers like me. The JIT shouldnt't be underestimated. Can you share the details of how you measured the performance?

Comment: You may want to 1. inspect the bytecode, 2. run the JVM with `-XX:+PrintCompilation` or something and see what's what; maybe the JIT is able to optimize the bytecode emitted by Java but not Scala.

Comment: If I uncomment the Thread.dumpStack I can see add method added only once in Scala stack frame. While in java add method is added incrementally in stack frame. Java even throws StackOverflow over 10K iterations. But the Java one does run 10 times faster than Scala for 1K iterations

Comment: What, you ran a program which sums up a 1000-element list *once*? You haven't measured anything worth mentioning. At the very least run the summation 10,000 times before starting the measurement; then run it for another 10,000 times with measurement and average the result.

Comment: You probably should use [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) for micro-benchmarks, it takes care of JIT warmup and clock granularity issues among other things.

Answer (score 6):

First of all the Scala method `add` you have shown is not in a (class) context. If you have this method in a class, the tail recursion optimization *cannot* be applied, since the method is neither `final` nor `private`. If you add `@tailrec`, compilation will fail. If I run it with 10000, it results in a stack overflow.

As for the Java version: The Java version is using a *mutable* `List`: The head/tail decomposition *alters* the underlying list. 
So after summing you can't use that list any longer, since it is empty.

Further the `List` in Scala has a completely different meaning than a Java `List`; the Scala list is meant for head/tail decomposition. As far as I know java.util.List has no tail method, and neither does the Java compiler apply tailrec optimizations, so the comparision is "unfair".

Anyway, I have run some JMH-based tests on different scenarios.

The only two scenarios you can really compare are "Scala while" and "Java for". They neither use OOP nor functional programming, it's just imperative.

**The results of five different Scala scenarios**

(Please scroll to the right, there is a small description in the last column)

```
Benchmark                   Mode   Samples         Mean   Mean error    Units
a.b.s.b.Benchmark5a.run    thrpt        10      238,515        7,769   ops/ms Like in the question, but with @tailrec
a.b.s.b.Benchmark5b.run    thrpt        10      130,202        2,232   ops/ms Using List.sum
a.b.s.b.Benchmark5c.run    thrpt        10     2756,132       29,920   ops/ms while (no List, vars, imperative)
a.b.s.b.Benchmark5d.run    thrpt        10      237,286        2,203   ops/ms tailrec version with pattern matching
a.b.s.b.Benchmark5e.run    thrpt        10      214,719        2,483   ops/ms Like in the question (= no tailrec opt)
```

- 5a and 5e are like in the question; 5a with `@tailrec`.
- 5b: `List.sum`: Was very slow
- 5c: Not a big surprise, the imperative version is the fastest one.
- 5d uses pattern matching instead of `if` (that would have been "my style"), I am adding the source of this one:

```scala
package app.benchmark.scala.benchmark5

import scala.annotation._
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.GenerateMicroBenchmark
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Scope
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.State
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.RunnerException
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.Options
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.OptionsBuilder

@State(Scope.Benchmark)
object BenchmarkState5d {
  val list = List.range(1, 1000)
}

class Benchmark5d {
  private def add(list : List[Int]): Int = {
    @tailrec
    def add(list : List[Int], sum: Int): Int = {
      list match {
        case Nil =>
          sum
        case h :: t =>
          add(t, h + sum)
      }
    }
    add(list, 0)
  }

  @GenerateMicroBenchmark
  def run() = {
    add(BenchmarkState5d.list)
  }
}
```

**The three Java scenarios**

```
Benchmark                   Mode   Samples         Mean   Mean error    Units
a.b.j.b.Benchmark5a.run    thrpt        10       40,437        0,532   ops/ms mutable (rebuilds the list in each iteration)
a.b.j.b.Benchmark5b.run    thrpt        10        0,450        0,008   ops/ms subList
a.b.j.b.Benchmark5c.run    thrpt        10     2735,951       29,177   ops/ms for
```

If you really want to compare in the meaning of functional programming style (= immutable, tail recursion, head/tail decomposition), than the Java version is five times slower.

As pointed out in a comment by Marko Topolnik:

> `subList` doesn't copy the tail, but it does something comparably bad, when applied to a `LinkedList`: it wraps the original list and uses an offset to accomodate the semantics. The result is that an O(n) recursive algorithm becomes O(n2)---the same as if the tail was repeatedly copied. Plus, wrappers accrete so you end up with the list wrapped a thousand times. Definitely not comparable to a head/tail list

```java
public class Benchmark5a {
    public static int add(List<Integer> list, Integer sum) {
        if (list.isEmpty()) {
            return sum;
        } else {
            int headVal = list.remove(0);
            return add(list, sum + headVal);
        }
    }

    @GenerateMicroBenchmark
    public long run() {
        final List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }
        return add(list, 0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Benchmark5a().run());
    }
}
```

---

```java
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
class BenchmarkState5b {
    public final static List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    static {
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }
    }
}

public class Benchmark5b {
    public static int add(List<Integer> list, int sum) {
        if (list.isEmpty()) {
            return sum;
        } else {
            int headVal = list.get(0);
            return add(list.subList(1, list.size()), sum + headVal);
        }
    }

    @GenerateMicroBenchmark
    public long run() {
        return add(BenchmarkState5b.list, 0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Benchmark5b().run());
    }
}
```

---

**Scala results in detail**

(all results only show the last scenario, and the overall results)

```
[...]

# VM invoker: /home/oracle-jdk-1.8-8u40/data/oracle-jdk-1.8.0_40/jre/bin/java
# VM options: <none>
# Fork: 1 of 1
# Warmup: 3 iterations, 1 s each
# Measurement: 10 iterations, 1 s each
# Threads: 1 thread, will synchronize iterations
# Benchmark mode: Throughput, ops/time
# Benchmark: app.benchmark.scala.benchmark5.Benchmark5e.run
# Warmup Iteration   1: 166,153 ops/ms
# Warmup Iteration   2: 215,242 ops/ms
# Warmup Iteration   3: 216,632 ops/ms
Iteration   1: 215,526 ops/ms
Iteration   2: 213,720 ops/ms
Iteration   3: 213,967 ops/ms
Iteration   4: 215,468 ops/ms
Iteration   5: 216,247 ops/ms
Iteration   6: 217,514 ops/ms
Iteration   7: 215,503 ops/ms
Iteration   8: 211,969 ops/ms
Iteration   9: 212,989 ops/ms
Iteration  10: 214,291 ops/ms

Result : 214,719 ±(99.9%) 2,483 ops/ms
  Statistics: (min, avg, max) = (211,969, 214,719, 217,514), stdev = 1,642
  Confidence interval (99.9%): [212,236, 217,202]


Benchmark                   Mode   Samples         Mean   Mean error    Units
a.b.s.b.Benchmark5a.run    thrpt        10      238,515        7,769   ops/ms
a.b.s.b.Benchmark5b.run    thrpt        10      130,202        2,232   ops/ms
a.b.s.b.Benchmark5c.run    thrpt        10     2756,132       29,920   ops/ms
a.b.s.b.Benchmark5d.run    thrpt        10      237,286        2,203   ops/ms
a.b.s.b.Benchmark5e.run    thrpt        10      214,719        2,483   ops/ms
```

---

**Java results in detail**

```
# VM invoker: /home/oracle-jdk-1.8-8u40/data/oracle-jdk-1.8.0_40/jre/bin/java
# VM options: <none>
# Fork: 1 of 1
# Warmup: 3 iterations, 1 s each
# Measurement: 10 iterations, 1 s each
# Threads: 1 thread, will synchronize iterations
# Benchmark mode: Throughput, ops/time
# Benchmark: app.benchmark.java.benchmark5.Benchmark5c.run
# Warmup Iteration   1: 2777,495 ops/ms
# Warmup Iteration   2: 2888,040 ops/ms
# Warmup Iteration   3: 2692,851 ops/ms
Iteration   1: 2737,169 ops/ms
Iteration   2: 2745,368 ops/ms
Iteration   3: 2754,105 ops/ms
Iteration   4: 2706,131 ops/ms
Iteration   5: 2721,593 ops/ms
Iteration   6: 2769,261 ops/ms
Iteration   7: 2734,461 ops/ms
Iteration   8: 2741,494 ops/ms
Iteration   9: 2740,012 ops/ms
Iteration  10: 2709,915 ops/ms

Result : 2735,951 ±(99.9%) 29,177 ops/ms
  Statistics: (min, avg, max) = (2706,131, 2735,951, 2769,261), stdev = 19,299
  Confidence interval (99.9%): [2706,774, 2765,128]


Benchmark                   Mode   Samples         Mean   Mean error    Units
a.b.j.b.Benchmark5a.run    thrpt        10       40,437        0,532   ops/ms
a.b.j.b.Benchmark5b.run    thrpt        10        0,450        0,008   ops/ms
a.b.j.b.Benchmark5c.run    thrpt        10     2735,951       29,177   ops/ms
```

---

**Update: Added another Java scenario 5d using `ArrayList`**

```
Benchmark                   Mode   Samples         Mean   Mean error    Units
a.b.j.b.Benchmark5a.run    thrpt        10       34,931        0,504   ops/ms
a.b.j.b.Benchmark5b.run    thrpt        10        0,430        0,005   ops/ms
a.b.j.b.Benchmark5c.run    thrpt        10     2610,085        9,664   ops/ms
a.b.j.b.Benchmark5d.run    thrpt        10       56,693        1,218   ops/ms
```

Comment: `subList` doesn't copy the tail, but it does something comparably bad, when applied to a `LinkedList`: wraps the original list and uses an offset to accomodate the semantics. The result is that an O(n) recursive algorithm becomes O(n2)---the same as if the tail was repeatedly copied. Plus, wrappers accrete so you end up with the list wrapped a thousand times. Definitely *not* comparable to a head/tail list. The fair way to compare would be building a small custom linked list implementation. Just substituting `ArrayList` would also show dramatic improvement.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Thanks for having a closer look at the the results. I have added your comment on `subList` in the answer. Using an `ArrayList` is a little better (see update in answer). I agree that the "comparison" is not fair, and I hope that one can read this in the answer clearly. Yet these results are an answer to the question. Anyway, even with an optimized data structure, there is still no tail recursion optimization, and then the stack will be Java's limit. But again, if speed really matters, then nothing beats the imperative way.

Comment: Yes, I usually suggest not to look at tail recursion as an *optimization*, but as an essential feature of the language which gives you another syntactic way to write plain iteration. At the end of the day, It's *semantics* that matter. But note that full TCO is something completely different, not reproducible with any other idiom. Basically, a controlled form of `goto`.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot draw any meaningful conclusions about performance from such a short experiment. You might have hit a garbage collection, there might have been some other process hogging your CPU, all classes may not have been loaded and the JVM might be optimizing your code all while your test is running. Any of which would adversely effect test results.

Processing 1000 elements will be extremely fast. You should make your experiment long enough such that inaccuracy in timing measurement or external influences have a smaller effect. Try with a million elements and if that still only take a few seconds try 10 million.

Consider running the test a few times when the JVM starts up before taking the measurement to "warm up" the JVM. You want to ensure that any classes that are lazy loaded have been loaded and that any realtime optimization performed by the JVM is complete before you start your test.

Repeat the experiment a few more times using the longer list of elements. Then throw away the fastest result and the slowest result and average the rest.

Comment: The main effects to eliminate are class initialization and measuring before the code has been JIT-compiled. BTW `nanoTime` is the only correct choice.

Comment: Thanks, I added some justification for warming up the JVM per your suggestion. I also removed the part about nanoTime. I agree it is the correct function to call.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik See http://shipilev.net/blog/2014/nanotrusting-nanotime/ `nanoTime` is the only choice _in the standard library_, but you still need to be careful.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov A nice article, yes. But I don't see your point: do you have in mind some alternative libraries which would improve on `nanoTime`? And about being careful, `nanoTime` is by far not the *only* thing you need to be careful about when microbenchmarking. Altogether, I just see truisms in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

The given scala example might be improved: with tail recursive functions in Scala, you usually provide a compiler hint using the `@tailrec` annotation.  See [here](http://tech.pro/blog/2112/scala-tail-recursion-optimisation-and-comparison-to-java) for more information.
[Note: updated due to typos]

Comment: You mean to say "...in Scala", don't you? As far as I am aware, the `@tailrec` annotation is from Scala, not from Java, isn't it?

Comment: You are absolutely right.  Fixed.  Thanks for the catch!

Comment: the annotation is not a compiler hint, but a check: You assume that the annotated function is tail recursive. The compiler will complain if it isn

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and the Scala version is about 5 times faster. It takes less than 4 seconds while the Java version takes nearly 20.

Java:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class ListTest {
  public static int add(List<Integer> list, Integer sum) {
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        return sum;
    } else {
        int headVal = list.remove(0);
        return add(list, sum + headVal);
    }
}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
    int sum = 0;

    long start = System.nanoTime();
    for(int j = 0; j < 1000000; j++) {
      list.clear();
      for(int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) list.add(i);
      sum = add(list, 0);
    }
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("time = " + ((end - start)/1e6) + "ms");
    System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
  }
}
```

Scala:

```
object ListTest {
  def add(list : List[Int],sum:Int): Int = {
    if (list.isEmpty) {
        sum
    } else {
        val headVal  = list.head
        add(list.tail, sum + headVal)
    }
  }

  def 

main(args: Array[String]) {
    val list = List.range(1, 1001)
    var sum = 0

    val start = System.nanoTime
    for(i <- 1 to 1000000) sum = add(list, 0);
    val end = System.nanoTime

    println("time = " + ((end - start)/1e6) + "ms")
    println("sum = " + sum)
  }
}
```

Comment: Why does your java version add all the elements to the list inside the measured loop, but not for scala?

Comment: @dhg Because the Java version uses `remove`, and the list is empty after summing.

Comment: You are including list building in the measurement. Naturally, Java turns out to be slower. You also do not exclude warmup from the measurement. All in all, the result demonstrates something quite irrelevant and uninteresting.