# Difference in the two loops. Which is more efficient and why?

Tags: scala, recursion

I happened to see a [Coursera tutorial](https://www.coursera.org/course/progfun) on Scala by Mr.Martin Odersky. To find the factorial of a number this is the function that was written by me.

```
  def factorial(n: Int): Int = {
    if (n == 0) 1
    else n * factorial(n - 1)
  }
```

However when I saw the video, Mr. Odersky had expressed it like so

```
def factorial(n : Int): Int = {
  def loop(acc: Int, n: Int): Int = {
    if (n == 0) acc
    else loop(acc * n, n-1)
  }

  loop(1, n)
}
```

What are the advantages of his code over mine? Which is more efficient and why?

Comment: Neither of these functions really works. Try evaluating `factorial(100000)`. The first throws `StackOverflow` because it isn't tail recursive, and the second returns `0` because of integer overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The others are right about tail recursion, but I'm a big fan of teaching a person to fish. Let's time the two versions

```
object factorial extends App {

  // we need a routine to time
  def time[A](name: String, expr: => A): Unit = {
    val start = System.nanoTime()
    val result = expr
    val time = System.nanoTime() - start

    println(s"$name took $time")
  }

  // non tail recurisve factorial
  def factorial1(n: Int): Int = {
    if (n == 0) 1
    else n * factorial1(n - 1)
  } 

  // tail recurisve factorial
  def factorial2(n : Int): Int = {
    def loop(acc: Int, n: Int): Int = {
      if (n == 0) acc
      else loop(acc * n, n-1)
    }

    loop(1, n)
  }

  //Some driver code
  val n = 200
  time("factorial1", factorial1(n))
  time("factorial2", factorial2(n))

}
```

On my box I get

```
$ scala factorial
factorial1 took 56000
factorial2 took 20000
```

(note, if I were serious about profiling this I wouldn't just run each version once)

Now let's look at the relevant bytecode

```
$ javap -private -c factorial$.class
Compiled from "factorial.scala"
public final class factorial$ implements scala.App {
```

But just the relevant bits. First, factorial1

```
public int factorial1(int);
  Code:
     0: iload_1
     1: iconst_0
     2: if_icmpne     9
     5: iconst_1
     6: goto          18
     9: iload_1
    10: aload_0
    11: iload_1
    12: iconst_1
    13: isub
    14: invokevirtual #120                // Method factorial1:(I)I
    17: imul
    18: ireturn
```

Line 14 recursively calls factorial1

Now factorial2 and its inner loop method

```
public int factorial2(int);
  Code:
     0: aload_0
     1: iconst_1
     2: iload_1
     3: invokespecial #125                // Method loop$1:(II)I
     6: ireturn

private final int loop$1(int, int);
  Code:
     0: iload_2
     1: iconst_0
     2: if_icmpne     7
     5: iload_1
     6: ireturn
     7: iload_1
     8: iload_2
     9: imul
    10: iload_2
    11: iconst_1
    12: isub
    13: istore_2
    14: istore_1
    15: goto          0
```

Note that the inner loop method (loop$1) doesn't recursively call itself. Instead instruction 15 does a "goto 0" to jump directly back to the top of the inner loop. That's the magic of tail recursion. We don't need to keep around a whole stack of intermediate results, we only need a tiny bit of information to compute the next thing.

Answer (score 2):

Both are *recursive*, but only the second one is *tail recursive*, and is therefore a candidate for *tail call optimization*. If this optimization is applied, the recursion is converted into a normal loop (that means no function calls, and therefore the costs of calling a function are removed).

In the 1st version the last operation is a multiplication, so the compiler cannot apply *tail call optimization*.

The 2nd version uses an accumulator, so that the last operation is the recursion (the recursive function call). Therefore *tail call optimization* can be applied.

If you add the `@tailrec` annotation, the compiler will check, if *tail call optimization* is really applied.

The Java compiler does not apply *tail call optimization*. As for Scala, the difference of "with TCO" and "without TCO" can bee seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28919779/2390083).

Answer (score 1):

As you see both solution use recursion. But second sample use `tail recursion` which allow to make some optimizations to reduce number of nested calls.

[More info about tail recursion](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TailRecursion)